# Drawing circle sections using HTML5 canvas - Math.PI

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wish I had the time to debug this & investigate the possible answers that popped up while writing this question, but I'll surely do so as soon as possible ;)

Onto my actual question:
I'm trying to draw curved shapes along a circle, but I can't figure out if this is a dumb error or the cry from a need of quadrants handling ( nb: I'm pretty new to those ;p )

From what I can tell, the code 'seems to work' fine for a single shape, yet it messes out when running from a loop to build shapes :/

Code that works for one shape ( & probably only at this location ;) )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var graphValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


// setup circle
// now onto drawing lines & stuff on a circle
var inner_radius = 20;
var radius = 80;
var point_size = 4;
var center_x = c.width/2;
var center_y = c.height/2;
var font_size = "20px";

// draw the circle
function drawCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawCircle();

// draw the inner circle
function drawInnerCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawInnerCircle();


var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length-1; // way A
var step360 = 0;

// another helper to draw lines from the outer part of the circle to the center
function drawCurvedSection(angle){
  var nextAngle = angle + horiStep360;

  var innerCircle_start_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_start_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var innerCircle_end_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_end_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;

  var outerCircle_start_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_start_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var outerCircle_end_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_end_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, angle, nextAngle);
  
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, angle, nextAngle);
  
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.stroke();
  // TODO: fill with random/diff color
}


//step360 = 0; // reset before reuse
/*
graphValues.forEach(function(val){
  //drawPoint( 180 - step360, 1, val); // way A reverse ( draw counterclockwise )
  //drawPoint( step360, 1, val); // way A
  drawCurvedSection(step360);
  step360 += horiStep360;
});
*/
//drawCurvedSection(step360);



var nextAngle = step360 + horiStep360;

ctx.beginPath();

//ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A - original
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, nextAngle*Math.PI/180, step360, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A


// randomized color
ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.fill();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Code that is still wip :/ ..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var graphValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


// setup circle
// now onto drawing lines & stuff on a circle
var inner_radius = 20;
var radius = 80;
var point_size = 4;
var center_x = c.width/2;
var center_y = c.height/2;
var font_size = "20px";

// draw the circle
function drawCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawCircle();

// draw the inner circle
function drawInnerCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
drawInnerCircle();


var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length-1; // way A
var step360 = 0;

// another helper to draw lines from the outer part of the circle to the center
function drawCurvedSection(angle){
  var nextAngle = angle + horiStep360;

  /*
  var innerCircle_start_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_start_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var innerCircle_end_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_end_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;

  var outerCircle_start_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_start_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var outerCircle_end_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_end_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  */

  ctx.beginPath();
  /*
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, angle, nextAngle);
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, angle, nextAngle);
  */
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, -Math.PI-nextAngle, true); // false :/
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // good ?
  
  ctx.closePath();
  //ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  //ctx.stroke();
  // TODO: fill with random/diff color
  ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
  ctx.fill();
}


//step360 = 0; // reset before reuse

graphValues.forEach(function(val){
  //drawPoint( 180 - step360, 1, val); // way A reverse ( draw counterclockwise )
  //drawPoint( step360, 1, val); // way A
  drawCurvedSection(step360);
  step360 += horiStep360;
});
//drawCurvedSection(step360);


/*
var nextAngle = step360 + horiStep360;
ctx.beginPath();
//ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A - original
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, nextAngle*Math.PI/180, step360, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A
// randomized color
ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.fill();
*/
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

This being said, I'll try on my side but I bet I'll have to do some tests before figuring it out ( and know why it glitches & how to fix it :) )

Wishing all the S.O. readers a very nice & sunny day ;)
+

-- Edit --

A quick test made it clear to what needs to be used but not why it isn't working - I hope it'll be clear soon ( .currently it draws pentagrams :/ )
-> what my question was actually about ( aside from knowing it my code was wrong on some other point(s):

`ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, (Math.PI*2/360)*<theAngle>, (Math.PI*2/360)*<theNextAngle>);`

( yup, that'd pretty dumb-dumb from me, but now I know ^^ )

[example attached below hosted on w3schools editor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG3QJ34X4MJT)

The following snippet demonstrate that it seems to work "manuallly" for stroked but I didn't check yet with shapes ( .. )

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, (Math.PI*2/360)*0, (Math.PI*2/360)*72);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, (Math.PI*2/360)*72, (Math.PI*2/360)*144);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, (Math.PI*2/360)*144, (Math.PI*2/360)*216);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, (Math.PI*2/360)*216, (Math.PI*2/360)*288);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, (Math.PI*2/360)*288, (Math.PI*2/360)*360);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.stroke();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is the last argument of the function ctx.arc

```
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,startAngle, endAngle, direction);
```

Direction if true tells the arc to be drawn counter clockwise else if false draw clockwise.

So if you draw from inside arc to outside you need to go anti clockwise then clockwise.

Eg

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const cols = [
  "hsl(0,100%,50%)",
  "hsl(40,100%,50%)",
  "hsl(70,100%,50%)",
  "hsl(100,100%,50%)",
  "hsl(150,100%,50%)",
  "hsl(250,100%,50%)",
];
var startAng = 0;
var endAng = 1;
var innerRad = 50;
var outerRad = 100;
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
function drawSlice(x,y,start,end,innerRad,outerRad,col){
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,innerRad,end,start,true);
    ctx.arc(x,y,outerRad,start,end,false);
    ctx.closePath(); // to close path for stroke command
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; count  < cols.length; i += 1){
    drawSlice(200,200,i,i+0.9,innerRad,outerRad,cols[count++])

}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas width= 400 height = 400></canvas>
```

Comment: I see you are still editing your answer -> thanks dude :)
Also, let me refine my question: since by default, the last argument of the ctx.arc fcn is false, what would need to be changed in the below code to make it work ?

`ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, -Math.PI-nextAngle, true); // needs a fix`
  `ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle);`

Comment: @StephaneAG The start and end angles need to be at the correct positions. Note in the answer the start and end angles are swapped. Also the angles are absolute angles (to me -step360 looks like its is an offset but could be wrong). So if last arg is true then its from ang1? anticlockwise to ang2?  and if false its from ang1? clockwise to ang2 for `arc(x,y,rad,ang1,ang2`

Comment: Thx for the quick reply: `var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length;`is to get  any number of sections of equal size, `step360`is used to know which angle we're at & deduce what will be the next angle. Ex: for 5 values, we go from 0° to 72°, 72° to 144°, 144° to 216°, 216° to 288°, and finally 288° to 260°.

Thing is: I can't get a formula using 'angle' & 'nextAngle' for start angle & end angle that works for every section, aka
`ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, step360?? ,nextAngle??, true); `
`ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, step360, nextAngle??);`

:/

Comment: @StephaneAG you go from 216-288 then you go backwards 288-260 so assume that is 360 not 260, Should not matter if you go past 360. But I think I am missing something in your explanations. As it is past midnight here and I have another answer to complete, I will have to have another look tomorrow and see what the problem is in your code.

Comment: don't worry no more & go elsewhere my friend: I got it working: what I was after was the following ( and yes, it's kinda dumb but .. ): 
`ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, true);
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, false);`

Nb: may I help on the other topic you're helping ? Now that this is done, I'd be glad to help ;)
-> now posting clear answer ( .. )
Thx +

Answer (score 1):

So, the right answer was ..

```
(..)
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, false);
(..)
```

-- Edit --

For even more clearer clarification, I forgot to convert degrees to radians before using them :/

```
var deg = angle; // angle in °
var rads = Math.PI/180*deg; // simpler yet same as (Math.PI*2/360)*deg
```

---

As a reminder, the `(Math.PI*2/360)*angleDegree` is just getting the degrees for both the angle & the nextAngle, while the 'trick' is to remember to switch the arguments order when passing the optional direction parameter.
So, the formulas needed within the function call were:

```
ctx.arc(x, y, rad, (Math.PI*2/360)*2ndAngle, (Math.PI*2/360)*1stangle, true);
ctx.arc(x, y, outRad, (Math.PI*2/360)*1stangle, (Math.PI*2/360)*2ndAngle, false);
```

Using stroke(), this renders:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var graphValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


// setup circle
// now onto drawing lines & stuff on a circle
var inner_radius = 20;
var radius = 80;
var point_size = 4;
var center_x = c.width/2;
var center_y = c.height/2;
var font_size = "20px";

// draw the circle
function drawCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
//drawCircle();

// draw the inner circle
function drawInnerCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
//drawInnerCircle();


//var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length-1; // made it work when testing single one ?!
var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length; // to gett ful 36° per item
// for 5 values:
// 0° -> 72°
// 72° -> 144°
// 144° -> 216°
// 216° -> 288°
// 288° -> 360°
var step360 = 0;

// another helper to draw lines from the outer part of the circle to the center
function drawCurvedSection(angle){
  var nextAngle = angle + horiStep360;
  console.log('current angle: ' + angle + '° & next angle: ' + nextAngle + '°');

  /*
  var innerCircle_start_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_start_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var innerCircle_end_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_end_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;

  var outerCircle_start_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_start_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var outerCircle_end_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_end_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  */

  ctx.beginPath();
  
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, angle, nextAngle);
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, angle, nextAngle);
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, -Math.PI-nextAngle, true); // false
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // good ?
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -angle, -nextAngle, true); // false
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -angle, -nextAngle); // good ?
  
  // debug
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, angle*Math.PI*2/180, nextAngle*Math.PI*2/180, true);
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, angle*Math.PI*2/180, nextAngle*Math.PI*2/180, false);
  // R: invert the angle & nextAngle AS WELL AS set optional direction parameter !!! -> WORKS !!!!
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, true);
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, false);
  
  ctx.closePath();
  //ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
  ctx.stroke();
  // TODO: fill with random/diff color
  //ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
  //ctx.fill();
}


//step360 = 0; // reset before reuse

graphValues.forEach(function(val){
  //drawPoint( 180 - step360, 1, val); // way A reverse ( draw counterclockwise )
  //drawPoint( step360, 1, val); // way A
  drawCurvedSection(step360);
  step360 += horiStep360;
});

//drawCurvedSection(step360); - to be called manually to step through & see where/why glitch begins
function debugDrawCurvedSection(){
  drawCurvedSection(step360);
  step360 += horiStep360;
}
//debugDrawCurvedSection(); // ok ..
//debugDrawCurvedSection(); // fucked up
//debugDrawCurvedSection();

/*
var nextAngle = step360 + horiStep360;
ctx.beginPath();
//ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A - original
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, nextAngle*Math.PI/180, step360, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A
// randomized color
ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.fill();
*/

// manual tests
/*
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, 0, 2, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2, false);
// randomized color
ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.fill();
*/
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Using fill(), this renders:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="300" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var graphValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas2");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");


// setup circle
// now onto drawing lines & stuff on a circle
var inner_radius = 20;
var radius = 80;
var point_size = 4;
var center_x = c.width/2;
var center_y = c.height/2;
var font_size = "20px";

// draw the circle
function drawCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
//drawCircle();

// draw the inner circle
function drawInnerCircle(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
//drawInnerCircle();


//var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length-1; // made it work when testing single one ?!
var horiStep360 = 360/graphValues.length; // to gett ful 36° per item
// for 5 values:
// 0° -> 72°
// 72° -> 144°
// 144° -> 216°
// 216° -> 288°
// 288° -> 360°
var step360 = 0;

// another helper to draw lines from the outer part of the circle to the center
function drawCurvedSection(angle){
  var nextAngle = angle + horiStep360;
  console.log('current angle: ' + angle + '° & next angle: ' + nextAngle + '°');

  /*
  var innerCircle_start_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_start_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var innerCircle_end_x = center_x + inner_radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var innerCircle_end_y = center_y + inner_radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;

  var outerCircle_start_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_start_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  
  var outerCircle_end_x = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  var outerCircle_end_y = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-nextAngle*Math.PI/180) * 1;
  */

  ctx.beginPath();
  
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, angle, nextAngle);
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, angle, nextAngle);
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, -Math.PI-nextAngle, true); // false
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // good ?
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -angle, -nextAngle, true); // false
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -angle, -nextAngle); // good ?
  
  // debug
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, angle*Math.PI*2/180, nextAngle*Math.PI*2/180, true);
  //ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, angle*Math.PI*2/180, nextAngle*Math.PI*2/180, false);
  // R: invert the angle & nextAngle AS WELL AS set optional direction parameter !!! -> WORKS !!!!
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, true);
  ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, (Math.PI*2/360)*angle, (Math.PI*2/360)*nextAngle, false);
  
  ctx.closePath();
  //ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  //ctx.strokeStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
  //ctx.stroke();
  // TODO: fill with random/diff color
  ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
  ctx.fill();
}


//step360 = 0; // reset before reuse

graphValues.forEach(function(val){
  //drawPoint( 180 - step360, 1, val); // way A reverse ( draw counterclockwise )
  //drawPoint( step360, 1, val); // way A
  drawCurvedSection(step360);
  step360 += horiStep360;
});

//drawCurvedSection(step360); - to be called manually to step through & see where/why glitch begins
function debugDrawCurvedSection(){
  drawCurvedSection(step360);
  step360 += horiStep360;
}
//debugDrawCurvedSection(); // ok ..
//debugDrawCurvedSection(); // fucked up
//debugDrawCurvedSection();

/*
var nextAngle = step360 + horiStep360;
ctx.beginPath();
//ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A - original
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, nextAngle*Math.PI/180, step360, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -step360, Math.PI-nextAngle); // PAIR A
// randomized color
ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.fill();
*/

// manual tests
/*
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, inner_radius, 0, 2, true);
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2, false);
// randomized color
ctx.fillStyle = '#' + ("000000" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8).toUpperCase()).slice(-6);
ctx.fill();
*/
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks everyone, I hope this helps someone else :)